# Google In App Purchase retrieve consumed purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using google in app purchase in our app. I need to query all the coonsumed purchases. How to do that?

Comment: You cannot get all , you can get past few by using `billingClient?.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Billing Library has no method of knowing that.
You have to keep count of consumed purchases by your own means, usually on a server or perhaps in Firebase.